# Convert a list of values to CSV values

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have a list of words and I want to convert them into a CSV.

```
a
b
c
d
```

to `a,b,c,d`

I replaced `\n` by `,` and it worked, but that was my 2 attempt

I first tried  this regex `^([A-Za-z ]+)$\n` and replacement is `\1,` . This particular regex is doing it for adjacent string like this:

```
a,b
c,d
```

What can I change in it to get it to work.

I am doing it in eclipse so I guess it is java, but I dont have to take into consideration the \ escape, it is same as edit+.

Comment: From `[regex]` tag description: **Please include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using, together with this tag.**

Comment: I agree with @LevLevitsky, the language is needed to sort this out.  I would say that `$\n` is kind of strange though.  `\n` is only at the end of the line, so you don't need both.  I would try removing `$` and see if that helps.

Comment: @dan1111 you are right, $ is redundant but removing it also will give result as shown in the post

Comment: @LevLevitsky included the tool and language I am using for regex

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
^([A-Za-z ]+)$\n
```

matches the beginning of a line, letters and space, then the end of the line.

Once you perform your first replacement, the line contains a comma, so it would no longer match that pattern.

The regex is also a bit redundant.  Because `\n` only comes at the end of a line anyway, you don't need both `$` and `\n` in your pattern.

In order to fix it, you simply need to let your pattern match a comma:

```
^([A-Za-z ,]+)\n
```

Note: the specifics might vary based on your Eclipse version and/or file encoding.  I needed  `\r\n` to match a newline in mine.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you don't even need to use regular expressions. Simply replace <strike>two</strike> one <strike>newlines</strike> newline  (`\n`) with a comma (`,`) and you're set.

Comment: According to the question, they are only separated by one newline.  If you are assuming that `\n$` matches two newlines, that is incorrect.  `$` matches the concept of "end of line" but is zero-width.  It doesn't actually match a character.

Comment: I just looked at the example he posted, which initially had two new lines, but has now been revised to one.